# SQL Server - FOR XML PATH : how to add xmlns:xsd to the root element?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xsd

I am using this query:

```
select 
    SalesOrderID, OrderDate, DueDate, rowguid 
from 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader
where 
    SalesOrderID between 43661 and 43662
for xml path('Order'), Root('AllOrders')
```

The output of this is:

```
<AllOrders>
  <Order>
    <SalesOrderID>43661</SalesOrderID>
    <OrderDate>2005-07-01T00:00:00</OrderDate>
    <DueDate>2005-07-13T00:00:00</DueDate>
    <rowguid>D91B9131-18A4-4A11-BC3A-90B6F53E9D74</rowguid>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <SalesOrderID>43662</SalesOrderID>
    <OrderDate>2005-07-01T00:00:00</OrderDate>
    <DueDate>2005-07-13T00:00:00</DueDate>
    <rowguid>4A1ECFC0-CC3A-4740-B028-1C50BB48711C</rowguid>
  </Order>
</AllOrders>
```

I want this as expected output (`xmlns:xsd` added):

```
<AllOrders xmlns:xsd="some schema URL">
  <Order>
    <SalesOrderID>43661</SalesOrderID>
    <OrderDate>2005-07-01T00:00:00</OrderDate>
    <DueDate>2005-07-13T00:00:00</DueDate>
    <rowguid>D91B9131-18A4-4A11-BC3A-90B6F53E9D74</rowguid>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <SalesOrderID>43662</SalesOrderID>
    <OrderDate>2005-07-01T00:00:00</OrderDate>
    <DueDate>2005-07-13T00:00:00</DueDate>
    <rowguid>4A1ECFC0-CC3A-4740-B028-1C50BB48711C</rowguid>
  </Order>
</AllOrders>
```

What modification do I make to query to achieve the above output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`XMLNAMESPACES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400%28v=sql.100%29.aspx);

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://foo.com/bar' AS xsd)
select SalesOrderID,OrderDate,DueDate...
```

Answer (score 3):

In general you can always convert to nvarchar(max) and do text replacements.

This means you can do it like this

```
select replace(cast((
    select SalesOrderID,OrderDate,DueDate,rowguid from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    where SalesOrderID between 43661 and 43662
    for xml path('Order'), Root('AllOrders')
) as nvarchar(max)), N'<AllOrders>', N'<AllOrders xmlns:xsd="http://foo.com/bar">')
```

Although I would much prefer you do it as per the suggestion from @AlexK